# column names on data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

Does anybody know how to avoid the following problem ?

```
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:20, nrow=10))
names(dat) <- c("TEST","eval_12")
dat$eval_1
dat$"eval_1"
dat[,"eval_1"]
```

As far as I understand, "eval_1" is not a name of the data.frame

Comment: It is because of partial matching.  Use `dat[['eval_1']]`

Comment: Thank you @akrun. The notation dat[,'eval_1'] does work. Is there any link explaning the difference in calling dat$eval_1 or dat [,eval_1]. There is a point that I do not get yet.